# login_onaccept actions not executed when logging in via CAS Consumer

Tags: web2py

I have two web2py applications (cas_provider, cas_consumer).

In cas_consumer I setup auth to use cas_provider as the cas_provider:

```
auth = Auth(db, cas_provider='http://localhost:8000/cas_provider/default/user/cas', host_names=configuration.get('host.names'))
```

In cas_provider I add the below code to db.py, to send an email when a user logs in:

```
auth.settings.login_onaccept.append(lambda form: mail.send(to='you@example.com', subject='new user',
         message='user email is %s'%form.vars.email))
```

If I go to http://localhost:8000/cas_provider/default/user and login directly to the provider, web2py logs that it tried to send the email.  However, if i go to http://localhost:8000/cas_consumer/default/user and login through the consumer, it appears that the login_onaccept function doesn't get called.

It appears that this happens because when I login through the consumer Auth calls `cas_login(version=2)`  which in turn calls `self.login(next, onvalidation, cas_onaccept, log)`.  Where *cas_onaccept* is a function defined in *cas_login*.  Since the onaccept parameter is provided (i.e. ^= DEFAULT) self.login does not pickup the settings.login_onaccept setting defined in db.py.

NOTE: auth.settings.login_onfail appears to work in both situations.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in the way login_onaccept is handled via cas_login?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug, so feel free to submit an issue, but for now, a workaround is to add some logic to the Auth action in the provider app. For example:

```
def user():
    if request.args(0) == 'cas' and request.args(1) == auth.settings.cas_actions['login']:
        return auth.cas_login(onaccept=auth.settings.login_onaccept[0])
    return auth()
```

The above code intercepts CAS login requests and explicitly passes the desired `onaccept` callback to `cas_login`. Note, the `onaccept` argument to `cas_login` must be a function rather than a list of functions, hence the `[0]` subscript in `auth.settings.onaccept[0]` (if `auth.settings.login_onaccept` is a list with more than one element, you'll need to create a wrapper function that calls each function in the list and pass the wrapper as the `onaccept` argument).